# How many parallel browser tabs can we open in puppeteer?

Tags: memory-management, parallel-processing, puppeteer, cpu-usage

Do we have any limiting factor other than hardware limits of memory and RAM that defines how many parallel tabs we can open in puppteer ?

I have tried on my windows laptop with 16 Gb RAM and was able to max out 20 parallel tabs.